# Easy way to upload images with shortcut or command line or drag drop

Tags: macos, markdown

I need a cloud service to storage image for blog.

I write my blog in markdown language,

I need to get the url of images after uploading those  to  the any cloud service.

Is there any cloud service or tool can let me do it ?

The url of images should be permanent  for my blog , thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Droplr](https://droplr.com/) can be used upload images right from the desktop by drag and drop to the menu bar icon.  The uploaded images can be embedded anywhere on the web and can be shared on social media.
 There are some handy features like auto copy of uploaded links to clipboard and system wide sharing extension on Yosemite.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Imgur](http://imgur.com) should do the job for you I think. You can upload loads of photos, and they stay where they are ;)